# Sliding Menu with Listview

Tags: android, list, view, menu, sliding

I`m actually using the SlidingMenu provided by Jfeinstein10, and im using a .xml which has an activity as behind view. Happens that, i want to use a ListView, that i read from a xml into this activity in behind view, but, looks like the sliding menu just takes the .xml file and dont call the activity. How should i proceed?

```
    public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e("TESTLOG", " ATIVIDADE 1 onCreate()");



    setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_android_list_view_activity);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.activity_emergency);
    getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
```

and this is the activity of the xml i want to be on the sliding menu:

```
    public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);
            String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q1);

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, questions));

    ListView lv = getListView();


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i);

      }
    });
}
   }
```

If i simply call this activity, the ListView works, but calling by the Sliding menu, dont.

Thank you!

Comment: Stick to android's documentation always. Just use other libraries as the last resort. Try to view this:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html